# 500 Error when trying to pass Python object to HTML using Flask/mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, flask, jinja2, mod-wsgi

I've got a Flask application running on top of Apache using mod_wsgi. I'm trying to pass an object I've created to a template like this:

```
@app.route('/<user>')
def viewUser(user):
    return render_template('viewuser.html', user = buildUser(user))
```

Where buildUser returns an instance of the class 'User' based on a username.

viewuser.html accesses some of the fields of 'user' like this:

```
Hello, {{ user.name }}!
```

This runs perfectly fine on the local Flask server, but my browser is returning a '500 Internal Server Error' when I try to access something like http://myurl.com/TestUser.

Templates otherwise are working fine - for example if I change the view function return value to:

```
return render_template('test.html', user = user)
```

and test.html contains:

```
Hello, {{ user }}!
```

Everything displays correctly. (http://myurl.com/TestUser displays 'Hello, TestUser!')

Does anyone have any idea why passing simple values works on Apache with mod_wsgi, but passing objects only works on the non-production Flask server?

Comment: Could be anything. Is there anything in the Apache log? Can you enable debug mode?

Comment: Turned on degugging and found some Python errors in my Apache log. This opened up a whole new can of worms, but I'll try to work through it before asking more questions.

Comment: What is `buildUser`?

Comment: I have a User class with fields like username, firstname, lastname, etc. buildUser is a function that takes a username, does some MySQL querying to get more information, then returns a fully populated User object.

Comment: Turns out there were just some errors in buildUser that the Flask server was able to deal with (with desired behavior) but mod_wsgi was not able to handle. I fixed everything up and it's working great now. Thanks @DanielRoseman!